# Function equivalence

Tags: python

I have to solve one task but I can't.

I have list of functions, and I must find in list the next one: function applies to some integer and returns x^2.

For example:

```
def f0(x):
    return str(x)

def f1(x):
    return x * x

def f2(x):
    return [x] * x

def f3(x):
    raise AssertionError

functions = [f0, f1, f2, f3]
```

My code:

```
k = lambda x: x*x
j = 0
n = int(input())
for i in functions:
    if i(n) == k(n):
        j += 1
print(j)
```

But checking system writes about EOFError, but it's okay in my terminal. How can I make it without applying in the body of loop?

Comment: Why do you take an input? Aren't there some test values your program could give to  `n` which would allow you to find which function is "square"?

Comment: There is no any info about that in task conditions.

Comment: I suppose I must make it without values but i have no ideas.